# MongoDB database restoration takes too much time

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongorestore, aws-documentdb

I encountered with the following issue. I was tasked to restore Mongo DB from a backup and I am using mongorestore.exe (on Windows OS) for it. Restoration process takes about 1,5h, a backup file size is about 25G (contains 25M documents).

I tried to restore both on an AWS Document DB cluster (instance type: db.r5.large) and on locally installed MongoDB (EC2-instance, r5n.large). I got almost the same time of the process (about 1.5h)

My question: Is it reasonable time for this operation and how can I optimize/reduce time that needs for this?

All advice is very appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at `--numParallelCollections` & `--numInsertionWorkersPerCollection` params, it may help you improve restoration speed

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Ayoub@, parallelizing with --numParallelCollections has helped many folks speed up the restore process. Also, you can additionally speed up the restore by scaling up the Amazon DocumentDB instance to a larger size for the duration of the restore and scale it back down to an r5.large when the restore is complete. Amazon DocumentDB charges by the second for instance costs to help minimize costs for these scenarios.